# How to get string inside react-bootstrap's textarea and send to function on button-click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have the following react-bootstrap code;

```
<Form>
  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
    <Form.Label>Example textarea</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} />
  </Form.Group>
</Form>
    
<Button
  variant="outline-primary"
  size="lg"
  active
  onClick={() => wave(TextAreaString)}
>
  Wave at Me
</Button>
```

The webpage looks like this;

[image]

When the button is clicked, I would like the function `wave(textarea_string)` to run. `textarea_string` is the string inside the textarea.

I am using React-bootstrap v2.4 and React v18

Comment: Have you tried looking at any react tutorial? You will want to use state in your component for this. Usually done with `useState`.

Comment: @super, thanks for the hint. I only start using React 3 days ago.

Comment: Yeah this might help you: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Define a state to hold the string value with the useState hook
- Define onChange handler to save the changed string value with the set-function of useState hook
- Read the value from state in your wave function

.

```
export default function App() {
  const wave = (text) => console.log(text);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const onChange = (event) => setValue(event.target.value);
  return (
    <div className="m-3">
      <Form>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
          <Form.Label>Example textarea</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            as="textarea"
            rows={3}
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>

      <Button
        variant="outline-primary"
        size="lg"
        active
        onClick={() => wave(value)}
      >
        Wave at Me
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-bassi-h85x27

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Upvoted. I've got trouble with this line `onClick={() => wave({value})}` Is this the right way to send {value}? For some reason, it seems {value} is empty

Comment: how does wave looks like on your side?

Comment: In your example you call wave with a string. in your comment you call it with an object. what's right?

Comment: Calling it with object that contains textarea string is what I want. I will correct this in the question.

Comment: I have corrected my answer and the codesandbox. You can call your wave function like this:  ```onClick={() => wave({textAreaString: value})}```. I don't know the property name you need. I called it "textAreaString"

Comment: Thanks. What worked on my code is `onClick={() => wave({value}["value"])}`. Your answer is good enough. I have marked it as the correct answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can only help you as long as you provide enough information. I have no idea how your objects look like

Comment: Yes. You have been most helpful. Thanks!

Comment: your code should be equivalent to: ```onClick={() => wave(value)``` Just pass "value" as parameter, thats's it.

Comment: Wonderful!! That works. So much simpler.